# Why are QCQP's convex according to the standard definition?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

According to wikipedia, this is the standard form of a convex program:
[image]

However, it doesn't seem to work when $g(x) = x^2 \geq 0$ (as in sum of squares optimization).

This is because to rewrite the above inequality in the standard form, we have:

$g(x) = -x^2 \leq 0$

Clearly, $g(x)$ is concave. However I see many references that says sums of squares optimization is convex. What gives?

http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/optimization.html#sums_of_squares

Comment: Constrained problem being convex is different of a function to be convex. I am not sure what you are giving us such deep reference, and asking for question regarding the convex problem definition.

Comment: I think you should explain your context better in order to your question make better sense.

Comment: It says right above in the definition of convex optimization problem that $g_i$ must be convex.

Comment: Ah! You forgot to put the "-" symbol in the "sum-of-squares optimization problem" name. Now I got it By the way, your $g$ function does not assume a sums-of-squares factorization, since it is negative function, hence it is not a sums-of-squares problem function type. But, for example, the function $h(x)=1+(x^2-y^2)^2$ is a sum-of-squares and it's not a convex function, since its set of minimizers is not convex. The main reason is that squaring convex functions does not necessarily make convex function.

Comment: Even though sum-of-squares functions are not necessarily convex functions, I think that some associated problem may be put into a convex and constrained optimization form via a proper identification. This type of construction must be done in books of this type of optimization problem, I suppose.

Comment: If this does not answer you, I suppose that it's needed  some effort describing what you actually want. Your title is quite suggestive, but what you have written not. Depending on how you describe your problem, I may be capable to answer.